# CSS and HTML for this below view

Tags: html, css

I am left with 2 labels and can't find solution.

[image]

I have done this much HTML and CSS

```html
<div id="incoming_call" class="bottom_toolbar_incoming_call" style="bottom:90px; position: fixed; right: 3px; z-index: 9999; height:45px; width:250px; background-color:lightgray;">

<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/766/base_software/128/circle_red.png" alt="Answer" style=" width:40px; height:40px;  display: inline-block; padding:2px; left:200px; position: relative;" id="Reject" />
<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/766/base_software/128/circle_green.png" alt="Answer" style=" width:40px; height:40px;  display: inline-block; padding:2px; left:100px; position: relative;" id="answer" />
</div>
```

Comment: Image link is broken

Comment: yeah no problem it is shown in my project

Comment: @TheodoreK. I want solution for this 2 label's css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

1. Takes care of vertical alignment (as it appears in your design)
2. Content height adjusts according to adjacent column
3. No browser issues as well
4. Red and Green color using CSS - Hence no images required

```css
.parent-container {
  width: 320px;
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.box__cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.b-red {
  background: red;
}

.b-green {
  background: green;
}

.t-green {
  color: green;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.list-item li {
  display: block;
}

.list-inline li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="box">

    <div class="box__cell box__cell--left">

      <div id="incoming_call">

        <ul class="list-item">
          <li class="t-green">Incoming Call</li>
          <li><b>00: 05</b></li>
        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="box__cell box__cell--left">

      <ul class="list-inline text-right">
        <li class="circle b-red">
        </li>
        <li class="circle b-green">
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would put the images inside a `position:absolute` div like this

```css
#incoming_call{
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#call{
  color:green;  
}
#images{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="incoming_call" class="bottom_toolbar_incoming_call" style="bottom:90px; position: fixed; right: 3px; z-index: 9999; height:45px; width:250px; background-color:lightgray;">
  <div id="call">call from 7040</div>
  <div id="time">0:01</div>
  <div id="images">
    <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/766/base_software/128/circle_red.png" alt="Reject" style=" width:40px; height:40px;  display: inline-block; padding:2px; left:200px; position: relative;" id="Reject" />
    <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/766/base_software/128/circle_green.png" alt="Answer" style=" width:40px; height:40px;  display: inline-block; padding:2px; left:100px; position: relative;" id="answer" />
  </div>
</div>
```